# What would be a comprehensive but safe set of html tags to use with the HTML Filter but compatible Markdown?

Tags: theming, input-formats

I want to use the Markdown filter on my pages, but using the HTML filter messes it up. However I still want to use it. Does anyone have an idea what other tags should be allowed beside these and what the safety issues are?

This the list I currently use - what else should be added?

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt>
<dd><div><img> <src><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6> <hr> <pre> <blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><table><thead><tr><th>
```

But you don't need enable all of it, just simple reorder the filters, and put the markdown filter under the html filter. So the html filter will drop the unavailable tags, before the markdown process the text, and build own html.

Edit:
Checked the OpenAtrium's dedicated Markdown filter, it has the following in HTML

```
<div> <span> <br> <a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <strike> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>
 <img> <blockquote> <p> <pre> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <table> <caption> 
<thead> <th> <td> <tr> <sup> <sub>
```

Markdown PHP Version: 1.0.1n
Markdown Extra Version: 1.2.4

And own filter weights:
[image: Atrium]

Comment: The markdown filter is the last filter, but I still need to disable the HTML filter to get correct Markdown